# FAILED_EMAIL_SENDING returning for some resends

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are resending envelopes in DocuSign using the below code. For some envelopes, we are receiving the following error code: "**FAILED_EMAIL_SENDING**" with the following message: “**Email sending failed. Error resending envelope.**” For other envelopes, it works perfectly fine. We are checking the status of the envelope beforehand and it is always in the "sent" status before sending.

```
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;

public void ResendEnvelope(Guid envelopeId)
Configuration apiConfiguration = GetApiConfiguration(); //Private method that gets our api configuration: works fine in other calls
EnvelopesApi envApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiConfiguration);
Envelope resendEnvelope = new Envelope()
{
    EnvelopeId = envelopeId.ToString()
};

EnvelopeUpdateSummary apiResponse = envApi.Update(AccountId, envelopeId.ToString(), resendEnvelope, new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions() { resendEnvelope = "true" }); //AccountId is set on class initialization: works fine in other calls
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.ErrorCode))
{
    throw new ApplicationException($"Resending Envelope in DocuSign returned the following error: Code: {apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.ErrorCode }; Message: {apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.Message}");
}
```

We notice that most of the emails that are failing have the domain "mailinator.com." I'm not sure what is the issue here. Thanks in advance for your support.

EDIT: Here is the log with our username omitted:

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/978711/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7?resend_envelope=true

TraceToken: c1cfa4a6-49d4-49d1-9724-3d9e54774c00
Timestamp: 2018-05-21T13:18:40.8694485Z

Content-Length: 53
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.1.0/csharp
X-DocuSign-SDK: C#
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"OMITTED", "Password":"[omitted]", "IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA
x-forwarded-for: 216.157.220.2

{"envelopeId":"bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7"}
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: c1cfa4a6-49d4-49d1-9724-3d9e54774c00

{
  "envelopeId": "bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "FAILED_EMAIL_SENDING",
    "message": "Email sending failed.  Error resending envelope."
  }
}
```

Note that we get the envelope less than a second beforehand and everything is working fine. I've omitted personal information from the below log:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/978711/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7?advanced_update=true&include=custom_fields%2C%20tabs

TraceToken: fc1b6fe7-2ef4-4df8-8268-d408e23187ae
Timestamp: 2018-05-21T13:18:40.0624901Z

Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.1.0/csharp
X-DocuSign-SDK: C#
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"OMITTED", "Password":"[omitted]", "IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA
x-forwarded-for: 216.157.220.2


200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: fc1b6fe7-2ef4-4df8-8268-d408e23187ae

{
  "status": "sent",
  "documentsUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/documents",
  "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/recipients",
  "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/attachments",
  "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7",
  "emailSubject": "OMITTED",
  "emailBlurb": "OMITTED",
  "envelopeId": "bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7",
  "signingLocation": "online",
  "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/custom_fields",
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": "336799242",
        "name": "CIF",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "OMITTED"
      }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": [
      {
        "listItems": [
          "E-Consent",
          ""
        ],
        "fieldId": "336799241",
        "name": "Envelope",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "E-Consent"
      }
    ]
  },
  "autoNavigation": "true",
  "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
  "notificationUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/notification",
  "enableWetSign": "false",
  "allowMarkup": "false",
  "allowReassign": "false",
  "createdDateTime": "2018-05-18T16:21:15.1870000Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-05-18T16:21:15.1870000Z",
  "initialSentDateTime": "2018-05-18T16:21:16.1700000Z",
  "sentDateTime": "2018-05-18T16:21:16.1700000Z",
  "statusChangedDateTime": "2018-05-21T12:59:38.7800000Z",
  "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/documents/combined",
  "certificateUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/documents/certificate",
  "templatesUri": "/envelopes/bb7220bd-626e-4d99-9b94-24aa68a57bb7/templates",
  "brandId": "c49a0181-23cc-4048-b8c5-ca4d091f540e",
  "purgeState": "unpurged",
  "is21CFRPart11": "false",
  "signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
  "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
  "allowViewHistory": "true"
}
```

Comment: can you share any one emailId for which it failed

Comment: Also, let us know if you did not see any error when you sent the envelope initially to this emailId, only on resend you are seeing the error from DocuSign in JSON response

Comment: @AmitKBist: Here is an example email for which it failed only on the resend: "mrafael@mailinator.com." All envelopes are working fine on the initial send.

Comment: I tried thru POSTMAN, it works fine everytime for your email address. Can you please capture the API logs when you are running from your code, follow the steps as explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) and update this qs with actual API request and response from the logs

Comment: I've updated the question with request and response from the logs for a failed resend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from DocuSign's Enterprise Support:

> With only this one envelope ID to check, I can’t be sure if more things aren’t in play here. But for that particular envelope referenced in Stack Overflow, it appears that the Resend is failing because the Sender is not the user attempting the Resend(s). The Sender is Laura Tribley, while the user attempting to Correct and Resend is ‘GreenStone eDocs’. I can’t tell if Laura has shared here folders with ‘GreenStone eDocs’, but if not then that would explain the error.

In short, make sure that if you set the "Send On Behalf Of" header with the initial send, you need to do the same for a Resend.

The corrected code:

```
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;

public void ResendEnvelope(Guid envelopeId, string senderEmail)
{
    Configuration apiConfiguration = GetApiConfiguration(sendOnBehalfOfEmail: senderEmail); //Private method that gets our api configuration: works fine in other calls
    EnvelopesApi envApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiConfiguration);
    Envelope resendEnvelope = new Envelope()
    {
        EnvelopeId = envelopeId.ToString()
    };

    EnvelopeUpdateSummary apiResponse = envApi.Update(AccountId, envelopeId.ToString(), resendEnvelope, new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions() { resendEnvelope = "true" }); //AccountId is set on class initialization: works fine in other calls
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.ErrorCode))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Resending Envelope in DocuSign returned the following error: Code: {apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.ErrorCode }; Message: {apiResponse.ErrorDetails?.Message}");
    }
}
```